# how to convert ResultSet to JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, cordova, jquery-mobile, resultset

We have tried to convert ResultSet into JSON object using following code :

```
var getAllCalelements = {};           // Object
    getAllCalelements['totalamount'] = [];          
    getAllCalelements['totalamount'].push(result.rows.item(i).totalamount);
    getAllCalelements['discount'] = [];          
    getAllCalelements['discount'].push(result.rows.item(i).invoicediscount);
    getAllCalelements['NetAmount'] = [];          
    getAllCalelements['NetAmount'].push(result.rows.item(i).namount);
    getAllCalelements['vat'] = [];          
    getAllCalelements['vat'].push(result.rows.item(i).vat);
    getAllCalelements['GrossAmount'] = [];          
    getAllCalelements['GrossAmount'].push(result.rows.item(i).gamount);
    getAllCalelements['bookOrder'] = [];          
    getAllCalelements['bookOrder'].push(result.rows.item(i).bookorder);

var json = JSON.stringify(getAllCalelements, undefined, 2);
```

But, We got JSON like this

```
{
  "totalamount": [19760.22],
  "discount": [ 7],
  "NetAmount": [ 18377],
  "vat": [ 8],
  "GrossAmount": [ 8],
  "bookOrder": [ "ABCANG00110"]
}
```

And, We need JSON output like this

```
[
    {
        "totalamount": 19760.22,
        "discount": 7,
        "NetAmount": 18377,
        "vat": 8,
        "GrossAmount": 8,
        "bookOrder": "ABCANG00555"
    }
]
```

I have tried but i am not getting desire output as mention above, I am getting JSON output. But We need JSON in the above format. All please guide me to get my desire output which is mention above, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var obj = [];

for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++){

    var getAllCalelements = {};           // Object
    getAllCalelements['totalamount'] = result.rows.item(i).totalamount ;
    getAllCalelements['discount'] = result.rows.item(i).invoicediscount;
    getAllCalelements['NetAmount'] = result.rows.item(i).namount;
    getAllCalelements['vat'] = result.rows.item(i).vat;
    getAllCalelements['GrossAmount'] = result.rows.item(i).gamount;
    getAllCalelements['bookOrder'] = result.rows.item(i).bookorder;
    obj.push(getAllCalelements);

}

var json = JSON.stringify(obj, undefined, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code :

```
var obj = {};
obj = [];

for(var i=0;i<result.rows.item.length;i++)
{
    var getAllCalelements = {};           // Object
    getAllCalelements['totalamount'] = result.rows.item(i).totalamount ;
    getAllCalelements['discount'] = result.rows.item(i).invoicediscount;
    getAllCalelements['NetAmount'] = result.rows.item(i).namount;
    getAllCalelements['vat'] = result.rows.item(i).vat;
    getAllCalelements['GrossAmount'] = result.rows.item(i).gamount;
    getAllCalelements['bookOrder'] = result.rows.item(i).bookorder;

    obj.push(getAllCalelements);
}
var json = JSON.stringify(obj, undefined, 2);
```

Output :

```
[
  {
    "totalamount": "19760.22",
    "discount": "7",
    "NetAmount": "18377",
    "vat": "8",
    "GrossAmount": "8",
    "bookOrder": "ABCANG00110"
  }
]
```

If you are adding second object to `obj` by `obj.push(getAllCalelements)` you will get below output

```
[
  {
    "totalamount": "19760.22",
    "discount": "7",
    "NetAmount": "18377",
    "vat": "8",
    "GrossAmount": "8",
    "bookOrder": "ABCANG00110"
  },
  {
    "totalamount": "19760.22",
    "discount": "7",
    "NetAmount": "18377",
    "vat": "8",
    "GrossAmount": "8",
    "bookOrder": "ABCANG00110"
  }
]
```

Comment: thanks for reply  i need like this
 [
  {
    "totalamount": 1000,
    "othervalue": "value"
  },
  {
    "totalamount": 2060,
    "othervalue": "value2"
  }
]

Comment: when i run you code it's data come like this [{}][{}] but we need like this [{},{},{}].Please help me

Comment: If you are agin push new object to `obj` by `obj.push()` than it will give output same as what you want.

Answer (score 1):

@aschattney Improvised on your answer and made it dynamic with `Object.keys()` also wrapped it in a function so you pass the `resultSet` i.e. in this case, `sqlResultSet` and it returns valid JSON.

```
  function returnJsonFromSqlResultSet(sqlResultSet) {

    var objArr = [];

    if (sqlResultSet.rows.length > 0) {

      var objKeys = Object.keys(sqlResultSet.rows.item(0)); //sample the keys from first element

      for (var i = 0; i < sqlResultSet.rows.length; i++) {

        var jsonObj = {}; // Object

        for (var j = 0; j < objKeys.length; j++) {
          jsonObj[objKeys[j]] = sqlResultSet.rows.item(i)[objKeys[j]];
        }

        objArr.push(jsonObj);

      }

      var json = JSON.stringify(objArr, undefined, 2);
      return json;

    }
}
```

Thanks!